# image cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, android

I am doing an android project to create an animation using eclipse.
On MainActivity.java 
it compiler shows 5 lint errors as follows

-image cannot be resolved or is not a field
-activity_main cannot be resolved or is not a field
-translate cannot be resolved or is not a field
-rotate cannot be resolved or is not a field
-shape cannot be resolved or is not a field

Here is doing there my code in MainActivity.java

```
    package ahmed103.appdemo;




    import android.R;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.view.animation.Animation.AnimationListener;
    import android.view.animation.*;
    import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.ImageView;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity implements AnimationListener {
ImageView image;
Animation animation1;
Animation animation2;
Button rotate, translate;
Context context = this;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
    rotate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.rotate);
    translate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.translate);
    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.shape);
    animation1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.rotate);
    animation2 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.translate);

    userInputHandler();
}

private void userInputHandler() {
    rotate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            image.startAnimation(animation1);

        }
    });

    translate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            image.startAnimation(animation2);

        }
    });

}

@Override
public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
    image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

@Override
public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
    image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

@Override
public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
    image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

}

Here is down there my activity_main.xml file

```
<html>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#DCDCDC"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
 android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
 tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="70dp"
    android:minHeight="150dp"
    android:minWidth="150dp" />

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</TableRow>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/rotate"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="@string/rotate_text" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/translate"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="@string/translate_text" />

</LinearLayout>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the below import

```
import android.R;
```

Also you have

```
<html> and </html>// should be removed from xml
```

Imnport

```
import ahmed103.appdemo.R;
```

And use

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

as the first statement in your `activity_main.xml`